# Mac:Windows 10 on PD10, missing media driver

Tags: mac, parallels, windows-10-preview

I am using Parallels Desktop 10 on OS X Yosemite GM.

I tried to install Windows 10 TP on my PD 10 but when I got into the installation phase, it informed that: "A media driver your computer needs is missing.". I have tried OS type Windows 7/8/Other, all had the same issue.

Where is the problem?

Comment: I can confirm the same thing on PD 9 and Yosemite.

Comment: Also on PD 10 on Mavericks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To solve this, go into the VM settings, and change the CD/DVD location to IDE 0:0.

Nick